# What approach is commonly used when a generic object needs to be converted into a specialized object?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, class

Let's say I have an instance of a superclass and at a later stage this object needs to be converted into a subclass instance (based on additional information that are stored in the object).

Is it acceptable to have a subclass constructor that takes a superclass object as an argument?

Edit:
A small but important detail: the information the superclass holds, needs to be available before the subclass is created. Therefore temporary states with a builder are not really an option.
A simple example: The superclass is an animal class which needs to provide information about the weight of the animal while the animal type is still unclear. At a later stage animal type is provided and with it additional information. Obviously the weight of the animal is still a relevant property.

Comment: Your new edit has made a good case for the builder pattern.  Your conclusion "Therefore temporary states with a builder are not really an option" is not supported by what you're saying.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to reconsider the use of inheritance for what you are trying to do. Converting an existing instance of an object into a new instance of its subclass is something unheard of and is not the way inheritance is supposed to be used. It defeats its purpose.

It seems pointless to have B descend from A when A merely provides some input for the construction of B.

If you give us some details about your problem we may be able to suggest a different approach.

[Edit after question update]

Your base class contains property values of your to be created animal. But that is not an animal. You will never use that first object in your program as an animal. So modelwise it makes no sense to use an animal class for temporarily storing creation parameters for an animal. Just call it AnimalConstructionParameters and make it a record or descend from Object.

Think of it this way. OO is supposed to make thinking about the real world easier by creating a model. Your model is not good because it adds confusion, it creates an animal just because it happens to have some fields that come in handy to store data. That is not helpful because the base animal does not represent an animal.

Comment: I wouldn't quite call it _unheard of_, but it is rare and raises a red flag about whether inheritance is being abused here. However, if you're e.g. dealing with someone being promoted from being a regular employee to a manager, it's possible for the code to convert the `Employee` into a `Manager : Employee`, without inheritance being particularly abused.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the *"object needs to be converted into a subclass instance"* part but a subclass accepting a superclass as a constructor parameter is very common. But the object is not being *"converted"*, it most probably copies the state of the object passed in the constructor (parameter can actually be of a type that is at the same level or even lower in the inheritance hierarchy). In the case the subclass is just a *wrapper*, then one could be using composition instead of inheritance.

Here is an example of what you ask in the very Java SDK:

[image: BufferedReader is a Reader]

`BufferedReader` is a `Reader`

[image: BufferedReader constructor takes a Reader as parameter]

`BufferedReader`'s constructor takes a `Reader` as a parameter

When inspecting the source code of `BufferedReader` one can see it's really a `Decorator`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it acceptable to have a subclass constructor that takes a superclass object as an argument?

There's no programmer police, so it is acceptable.  But without any details we cannot provide anything but general guidance.

We model for purpose: to accomplish something — or more specifically in support of some automation scenario.  Modeling without purpose or objective generally does not result in a satisfactory design, when purpose is ultimately considered (the design has a good chance of being overbuilt or underbuilt).  So, consider carefully the automation scenarios you're trying to support, and model to that purpose.

Software is soft: it can be changed, so if a new purpose (automation scenario) comes along, we can refactor/redesign the code to support that.  So, start with the simplest possible design for the known purpose and evolve if it either doesn't meet the needs or the purpose changes.

Inheritance is a tool for organizing programmed behaviors for code reuse.  It is far from perfect, and certainly not the only tool we have for modeling.  As simple proof, features of and approaches to inheritance differ quite a bit across all the OOP languages.

Consider composition over inheritance.  In your scenario, the base class might be split into two separate classes: a configuration class that holds state (and is not a base class) and a lightweight base class, which composes with the configuration class (i.e. the base class refers to an instance of the configuration class).  The base class could be abstract, and subclass constructors can take the configuration class as parameter to capture and bind the new instance with its configuration.

As @Martin says, it would be a rare pattern to create a base-class object first, and then later create a subclass object equivalent as a replacement, e.g. when more is known (like which subclass to create).  (Often base classes are marked abstract so they cannot have concrete instances.)  Ideally, just wait until the subclass can be created directly — but when that's not possible perhaps use a builder pattern to hold the temporary state before creating the subclass.  The advantage of the builder pattern is that it is hard to mistake a builder instance for a well-formed instance of the intended subclass.

Comment: Added a small example as well as an additional constraint.